# Bootstrap - fixed columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a database and I'm using Bootstrap for the design but I'm not really familiar with it. No matter how I edit the tags for the table, I couldn't get it right. 
My database looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj5jz.jpg and as you can see, there is a big space at the sides. I would like them to be narrower. Also, when I try to insert a new entry, the structure became like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk0pb.jpg. Is it also possible to align the search field to the find button? Below is the code of that page. Thanks a bunch!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3><center>Library & Archives Collection</center></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <a href="new.php" class="btn btn-success">New</a>
                <form align=right action="search.php" method="GET">
                    <input type="text" name="query" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Find" class="btn btn-success" />
                </form>
                </p>

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th><center>File Name</center></th>
                          <th><center>File Type</center></th>
                          <th><center>File Path</center></th>
                          <th><center>Description</center></th>
                          <th><center>Notes</center></th>
                          <th><center>File Size</center></th>
                          <th><center>Volume & Page Number</center></th>
                          <th><center>Action</center></th>
                          <th><center>Image</center></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php
                       include 'database.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM collection ORDER BY id DESC';
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td width=75>'. $row['filename'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=75>'. $row['filetype'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=75>'. $row['filepath'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=150>'. $row['description'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=150>'. $row['notes'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=75>'. $row['filesize'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=100>'. $row['volumepagenumber'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=150><center>';
                                echo '<a class="btn" href="view.php?id='.$row['id'].'">View</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="edit.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Edit</a>';
                                echo '&nbsp;';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                                echo '<td width=100>'. $row['image'] . '</td>';
                                echo '</center></td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }
                       Database::disconnect();
                      ?>
                      </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you paste the rendered HTML?

Comment: Hi! I already posted the codes up there.

Comment: Rendered HTML is the output you see on your browser. _Right-Click->View Page Source_

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger, thanks! Sorry, didn't read that carefully. The rendered HTML code is the same as the one I posted though, but below is the first part:

(https://docs.google.com/document/d/19DLNJR-K8oiqvTgfrOEkzLzSWipK0jkobeD6Zi_y9Ic/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Seems like your document is restricted, sent you an access request.

Comment: Sorry again. I already edited the privacy settings. You can view it now. Sorry again for the trouble and thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the text you have tried to enter is a continuous words, if there was a space, it would have been shifted to next line or else the table keeps increasing its width accordingly.  Honestly, I couldn't find a work around for this.

Besides that the space in the sides that you are talking about comes from the `.container` class, so with a little bit of CSS, we can make the table fit the screen:

```
.container-center{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
<div class="container .container-center col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
```

The `col-md-12, col-xs-12, col-lg-12` classes form the bootstrap grid and help to view the table fit the screen. More about them [here.](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

As for the aligning of the *find* button with `input`, you can add this css:

```
input[type=text].form-control{
display:inline-block;
width:auto;
vertical-align: middle;
}
<input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" />
```

The `form-control` class designs your `input` box the *boostrap way.*

You can view how it looks here:

**[Full Result](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yrt8/3/embedded/result/)** (*[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yrt8/3/))*

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping me. I did what you posted there. The aligning of the find button worked. The only problem now is that the cells are expanding. :( Also, I forgot to mention a while ago that I was using version 2 of bootstrap so when I changed it to the latest versioin, everything formatted to the right side of the screen. (https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Jcy72VUA4tnwD7AFw-T88L_yzAl2oUXd7XDZ4JV-I9Y/edit?usp=sharing) Am I missing something?
Here's the rendered html of the Add Page (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nHiFBOs5VS10t1elGPnMZVx09OlN0h6o4HcrBv0JsJ4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @user3463024 Like I mentioned, the cells _will_ expand if you have continuous text without a space like 'thisisalonglonglonglongtext'. So don't try that kind of text for testing. Also, you could try to separate the % of the width proportionately among the table headers as `<th style="width:10%">`. And on the 'Add' page I don't see anything on the right? Did you mean it's left-aligned?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I meant left-aligned. Also, I tried inputting entries with proper spacing but the cells are still expanding unlike the first entries.

Comment: Hello! Thanks! I tried your suggestion and the text for each cell is now centered vertically. There isn't change for the other pages, though.

Comment: @user3463024 You want the text and inputs in add page to be center aligned?

Comment: Hello again! Yes, I want them to be center-aligned. When I was using version 2 of Bootstrap, they were center-aligned but when I replaced it with the current version to check if the problems with the other parts will change, the other pages went to being left-aligned from center-aligned.

Comment: @user3463024 Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xhL79/embedded/result/). The grid classes for bootstrap 3 is different, instead of `span10` and `offset1`, I've applied `col-md-10 col-md-offset-5`

Comment: Hi again! I did that and it worked! Thanks a lot. The original style looks like this (https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/19rPQtxABsuEXXLlgsHaqjLHt5_p70zeEmBBLvx3JH4M/edit?usp=sharing) Sorry for a asking a lot but thanks so much!

Comment: @user3463024 That looks neat, and you're welcome. Please click the tick mark at the left to mark your problem as solved.